# Is my interpretation of this sentence correct

Tags: translation, meaning, sentence

日本に思いを馳せてる。。。

Based on the words I would guess this sentence means 'I desire to go to Japan' or 'My thoughts drift to Japan'

Not entirely sure how to translate it properly but that's what I would think it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in terms of the "image" of 日本に思いを馳せてる, your second translation is more accurate, but both would work fine. You could also say "I'm dreaming of Japan/going to Japan." I like your second choice though, it has a very "literary" feel to it.